# Background GPS Polling from Web Service

Tags: android, iphone, service, gps, web

I'd like to know if this is possible on either Android or iPhone:

I would like to have an application run in the background of the phone and send a GPS location to the server every N minutes.  As far as I know this is difficult on the iPhone, but can it be done on an Android?

Thinking a bit more on the iPhone - could I create a web service that runs timers for each application and, on timer elapse, push a notification to the phone to start the GPS service and send the location information back to the server?  Can I push notifications to an iPhone application in the background?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re Android: yes, this is also possible, and just as with the iPhone, the less accuracy you need, the faster this will be. It is also asynchronous , so you will need a similar approach. As opposed to the iPhone though, you can start the GPS and wait for location updates in a background service, so that you can send the current location to the server whenever you have it.

Answer (score 2):

Re iPhone: yes, you can push notifications when the app is in the background, but you should know that the location services API is an asynchronous API (having been working on it myself...:)) so you can't time it per se (you can for example "expose" it every N seconds, saving the last location that was provided - so essentially implementing a logic that will make it asynchronous, but with a certain cost to the user experience).

Also note that having location services running in the background is a huge drain of battery. here it really depends on the type of application that you are building. If you dont need high accuracy (say, knowing the city is enough) you could set the accuracy of the API to be large, which wont trigger WiFi and GPS, and will use only cell - less battery drain. If you need really high accuracy (street corner, etc.) this wont be super useful for you.

Adding some more info for your convenience: like I mentioned, accuracy requirement will trigger the different location services, which in return affect batter consumption. In general the accuracy is:

GPS: ~10 meters
WiFi: ~100 meters
Cell: 500 meters (urban canyon environment) to 50Km (in open environment)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was going to leave all location services off - then only start them when the phone received a push notification (and quickly turn them off right afterward).  Is it not possible to start/stop them with push notifications?

Comment: yes it is possible, but not sure you will have time to receive the position from the API until your turn them off again.